# Custom uibarbutton also changes the buttons in the email form

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, customization, uibarbuttonitem

I'm unsure as to what I've done here.

After a few hours trying to create custom nav buttons I finally settled on this piece of code:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:uiBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It works well, too well.

I've implemented it in the `appDelegate.m` file and it's decided to also change the buttons the email window uses.

How can I revert these back to the standard UI buttons?
The only other option would be for me to change the bar to match these buttons like I did with the rest of the app, but I want to keep the email form feeling separate.

I'd post a screenshot but I'm still new here.

Comment: maybe you can overwrite the effect for the barbutton of the email form like - whatever the name is, say emailButton
[[emailButton appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: The trouble is I don't have a name for the built in email button that comes with MFMailComposeViewController. 


The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for MFMailComposeViewController states this:

_Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application._


So, I'm not really allowed to do anything like that.

Comment: instead of emailbutton use UIBarButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` method (see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn%3a)) to set a different configuration for a set of classes, in your case:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: This is indeed what **lead** me to the solution. I used the same idea, but a little backwards. Implementing the code for the buttons I **did** want to change, rather then the ones I didn't. 

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[viewWithCustomButtons class], nil] setBackgroundImage:uiBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`